# Compile Fortran program with IFORT and using object files (i.e. .lib) compiled in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a basic question that I cannot find the answer to even after searching the web many times.

Is it possible to compile a Fortran program by IFORT that uses (as dependencies) object files (i.e. .lib) that were compiled by Microsoft Visual Studio C?

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? Assuming that IFORT runs on windows as well it should be possible.

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, and is even rather easy. You have several options for how to do this:

- Add the MSVC library project to your Fortran Visual Studio solution and then use Project > Dependencies to add the C project as a dependent of your Fortran project *does not work if the C project creates a DLL)
- Add the .lib from the C project to the Fortran project as if it were a source file
- Name the C .lib in the Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies project property.

I generally recommend the first choice, as it means you don't have to fuss with different settings for Debug and Release projects. You do need to make sure that the C library is built to specify the same run-time library type (Debug vs. Nondebug, DLL vs. Static) as the Fortran project. This is in the Code Generation property page for C.

There is a worked example "Fortran Calls C" in the [Intel Parallel Studio XE for Windows Sample Bundle](https://software.intel.com/en-us/product-code-samples).

You'll also need to understand how to call a C procedure from Fortran and ensure that the C arguments have compatible Fortran types. It works best if you make use of the Fortran standard's "C interoperability" features.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is possible @Steve! I managed to successfully compile a Fortran shared library using IFORT that contains some .obj files compiled by Visual Studio C. I am now trying to use this Fortran shared library in a Fortran program, but it fails saying "Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TEST_mp_EXECUTE referenced in function MAIN__". When I use the tool dumpbin.exe I can see that function "test_execute" is in the Fortran Shared library. Do you have any idea why this mismatch of names that is making the compilation of the Fortran program to fail?

Comment: TEST_mp_EXECUTE means it is a procedure EXECUTE in module TEST. It is not clear to me which language has the procedure and how you have declared it. Please show a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.